# How to validate coupon code on wishlist page on magento?

Tags: magento, coupon

How can we validate coupon code on a custom form on wishlist page? Is there any way to check the validity of the coupon code with ajax functionality?

I have used the following code, but it always return valid message:

```
    $codeLength = strlen($couponCode); // $couponCode is the coupon code entered by the user.
    $isCodeLengthValid = $codeLength && $codeLength <= Mage_Checkout_Helper_Cart::COUPON_CODE_MAX_LENGTH;
    if (!Mage::getSingleton('checkout/cart')->getQuote()->getItemsCount()) {
       exit('No items in cart');

    }
    Mage::getModel('checkout/cart')->getQuote()->getShippingAddress()->setCollectShippingRates(true);
    Mage::getModel('checkout/cart')->getQuote()->setCouponCode($isCodeLengthValid ? $couponCode : '')
        ->collectTotals()
        ->save();
    if ($codeLength) {
        if ($isCodeLengthValid && $couponCode == Mage::getModel('checkout/cart')->getQuote()->getCouponCode()) {
            $msg = 'Coupon code applied';
        } else {
            $msg = 'Coupon code is not valid';
        }
    } else {
        $msg = 'Coupon code was canceled.';
    }
```

Simply, I have tried on cart items on ajax page. But it didn't work. I am a newbie in magento. Any help appreciated..

Comment: What have you tried? What code do you currently have? Questions with code are 1000% better than those without.

Comment: it always returns a valid message even if the code is wrong..

Comment: Added the code.. Can you please check and provide any suggestions? @Enigmativity

Comment: The question is much improved, but I'm not a PHP nor Magento developer. I'm afraid I can't help.